# What is it meant by Allah hates the person that has beautiful speech who move their tongue around like a cow?

Tags: hadith-interpretation

The prophet (peace and blessings be upon Him said):

> إِنَّ اللَّهَ عَزَّ وَجَلَّ يُبْغِضُ الْبَلِيغَ مِنَ الرِّجَالِ
> الَّذِي يَتَخَلَّلُ بِلِسَانِهِ تَخَلُّلَ الْبَاقِرَةِ بِلِسَانِهَا
>
> Allah , the Exalted, hates the eloquent one among men who moves his
> tongue round (among his teeth), as cattle do
>
> [Sunan Abi Dawood, graded as Saheeh](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/233)

What did the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon HIm) mean by moving the tongue around like a cow?  what have scholars said regarding this Hadith?

Answer (score 2):

The Hadith does not condemn those who speak in an eloquent and clear voice, and use it to spread truth/good.  Rather it condemns those who use it for evil, those who speak, and make their speech long, those who cross the limit when speaking.  The Hadith likens the person who does this to a cow who moves it's tongue around, and eats with it's tongue, while the rest of the animal eats with it's teeth.

Sources: [Explanation on the Hadith (in Arabic)](http://www.djelfa.info/vb/showthread.php?t=682301)